# How to control which version of Powershell Puppet shells out to on Windows?

Tags: windows, powershell, puppet

Microsoft recently changed their download repository for Windows Powershell to require TLS 1.2+ which Windows Powershell 5.1 doesn't support without the runtime setting change to `Net.ServicePointManager`.

Can I change Puppet to use Pwsh (7.x) as the default or is there some Puppet code I can change to inject the `Net.ServicePointManager` snippet into to configured 5.1 to support TLS 1.2 in all Puppet initiated Windows Powershell sessions?

The underlying issue I'm trying to solve is `package` failing with an error similar to [this](https://github.com/hbuckle/puppet-powershellmodule/issues/22).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in an old `windowspowershell` provider. The fix is documented [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/923588/install-powershell-gallery-module-using-puppet#comment1331293_924123).

Answer (score 0):

The puppetlabs-powershell module has a short example in the readme on how to use PowerShell6/7 instead of 5.1 by using the `pwsh` provider instead of the `powershell` provider: https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-powershell#requirements

To use the `pwsh` provider, change the `provider` line to `pwsh` and set the `path` if your pwsh install is not on PATH.

```
exec { 'RESOURCENAME':
  ...
  path     => '/usr/alice/pscore',
  provider => pwsh,
}
```

Comment: Sorry, this is in regards to how the package module calls out to Powershell. Not the actual PowerShell module. I'm not sure I am really asking the question correctly.

Comment: If we forked the `cholocatey` provider, could we change this [line](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-chocolatey/blob/master/manifests/install.pp#L48) to `pwsh`?